# Auto-smooth bevel object

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to make an achitrave using a path with a bevel object. It works pretty well! But I can't get the shading right. When set to flat shading it looks good except you get the faceted reflections on the smooth bits:

[image: flat]

If I set smooth shading it screws up the sharp edges:

[image: smooth]

There is an "autosmooth" option for normal meshes that would solve this, but I can't use it on paths. Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Keep smooth shading but simply use 2 very close control points at your sharp edges. This way you can control your bevel shading perfectly, the closer the points, the sharper. The drawback is added geometry (one additional curve segment).

Here is a sharp edge with a single control points. No sharp edge:

[image]

Instead, the same edge but using 2 control points very close to each other:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the bevel modifier, set the `Limit Method` to `Weight`. Select the edges you want to have sharp and press and in the item menu adjust the `Bevel Weight`. Keep in mind that higher you go, less sharp will the edge be - 0.01 is the sharpest. If it's for some reason not enough, you can increase the number of segments inside the bevel modifier.[image]

Comment: I'm not using the bevel modifier. I'm using the "bevel object" (yeah that is really badly named - should be called "sweep object" or "extrude object" or something like that).

Comment: Oh, yeah, I thought you're using the bevek modifier. :)